# Position set of elements which only show on hover

Tags: css

I have a group of elements, each of which contain a child element with a more detailed set of data. The detailed data only shows when you hover over the parent element.

When I first coded it, I had the subdata on the same level as the parent data, so it had a fair amount of space, and could be position relative to the top of the grandparent container.
[The red box (aging_detailed_breakdown) only shows when one of the black boxes (aging_line) is hovered over.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9Wr.png)

However, it turns out that the red box could be expected to hold a lot of data and needed a scrollbar. In order to use the scrollbar, I put the red box within each of the black boxes. Now I am having a problem with positioning.

If I position it absolute, it positions to the level of each black box, so the lower hover elements are very low and look like this:
[cut off element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r45NX.png)

So I tried to do fixed, and when the page is scrolled to the top it looks just fine. But then if you scroll down, the hover element follows you, out of its place.

Any ideas? I want that div in its place, even if you scroll down.

I work in a company that frowns on sharing code, this is what I can share:

```css
.aging_detailed_breakdown {
    display: block;
    width: 156px;
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 79px;
    left: 1367px;
    height: 188px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.aging_detailed_breakdown.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="aging_line">     
    <div class="ib age_count">{!customerAnalyze.over0count}
        <div class='aging_detailed_breakdown hidden'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aging_line">     
    <div class="ib age_count">{!customerAnalyze.over0count}
        <div class='aging_detailed_breakdown hidden'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aging_line">     
    <div class="ib age_count">{!customerAnalyze.over0count}
        <div class='aging_detailed_breakdown hidden'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aging_line">     
    <div class="ib age_count">{!customerAnalyze.over0count}
        <div class='aging_detailed_breakdown hidden'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your code please.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I added code. This is what we are going with for now, (fixed position) until someone complains or we find a better solution. Any suggestions till welcome.